# Django - Can't access variable defined with template tag outside for loop

Tags: python, django, templatetags

In a Django template, I have to signal that the `if` conditional was entered and for this I created a template tag:

```
@register.simple_tag
def setvar(val=None):
    return val
```

And in my template I have:

```
<div>
    {% for item in items %}
        {% if <!-- condition --> %}
            {% setvalor '1' as has_favorites %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    <div>{{ has_favorites }}</div>  <!-- testing -->
</div>
```

The variable `has_favorites` is not rendered in the browser. It seems that the variable is only available in the `for` loop scope.

Is there a way to workaround that?

Comment: Please don't do this in the templates. This belongs in the view, where you annotate the `items` with a field that specifies if has favorites.

Comment: Can you share your view, and the relevant model(s)?